# How to save a result from postgres function into a variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

I have a Postgres function which should return a column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  fillvals_v1 (source_column numeric , order_by_col numeric) RETURNS numeric AS $$
    DECLARE
      fv_value numeric;
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
              select
                  first_value(src_col) over (partition by partition_col) as corrected_col
                      from (
                          select source_column as src_col, order_by_col,
                              sum(case when source_column is not null then 1 end) over (order by order_by_col) as partition_col
                                  from table_name
              ) t into fv_value;
              return cast(fv_value as numeric);
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

The table, table_name is having values like this

```
seq | close
-------+-------
     1 |     3
     2 |     4
     3 |     5
     4 |
     5 |
     6 |     3
(6 rows)
```

So when i call this function like this

```
select fillvals_v1(close, seq) from table_name;
```

it gives me the below result

```
fillvals_v1
-------------
           3
           4
           5


           3
(6 rows)
```

which is not correct.

The actual result I want is

```
   seq | close
-------+-------
     1 |     3
     2 |     4
     3 |     5
     4 |     5
     5 |     5
     6 |     3
(6 rows)
```

That is, I want all the gaps filled with the latest values (ordered by `seq`) that is not NULL.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here? Maybe there is something that is missing in my function, or the way I save the function result into the variable might not be correct.

Comment: This approach is *very* inefficient, since the function and the complicated query in it will be run for every result row. You had better write that in a single query. If you describe the desired result, we can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `IGNORE NULLS` option on `LAG()`.  Alas, Postgres does not (yet?) support that.

I would recommend:

```
select t.*, max(close) over (partition by grp)       
from (select t.*,
             count(close) over (order by seq) as grp
      from tablename t
     ) t;
```

You can also use a lateral join (or subquery):

```
select t.seq,
       coalesce(t.close, tprev.close) as close
from tablename t left join lateral
     (select tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.seq < t.seq and
            t.close is null and
            tprev.close is not null
      order by tprev.seq desc
     ) tprev;
```

The first method should be faster, though.